# Azure Website Memory Leak with Application Insights

Tags: azure, memory-leaks, azure-application-insights

[image: memory leakage]

It is clear that there is some memory leakage here.

I made a diagsession dumpfile with the http://.scm.azurewebsites.net api, and it looks like it has something to do with Application Insights. 
Also because there is the notion 'cycle detected' below in the screen.

[image]

Is this the correct conclusion from this data?
What could be the next step to take? (I yet have thrown away the application insights in de portal, doesn't help)

Comment: No answer, but what are you using to get the managed memory?  That would be very helpful [for my own problem]. 

Also, I have noticed that AppInsights causes my application to die for about 5 minutes when doing a VIP Swap between staging and production.  I removed app insights and the problem went away.

Comment: @RaySülzer I explained that for you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411318/investigating-memory-leaks-in-azure-without-powershell). Please tell me what exactly you removed to remove app insights.

Comment: I removed the entire app insights package from the solution. But, I added it back since the downtime of 5 minutes was manageable in my case. But, I think the entire package has issues that need to be resolved if I were to use it on a large service.

Comment: I haven't noticed any memory leak issues though.