# investigating memory-leaks in azure without powershell

Tags: azure, memory-leaks, memory-dump

Can I investigate memory-leaks in azure without powershell? 
I know it is discribed to download memorydumps with use of powershell-commands on several places on the web but I just hate to work with error-prone handtyped commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, actually it is very easy.

Navigate to the website in question with use of the internal url. For example http://yourwebsitename.azurewebsites.net/. Then add the letters .scm. after your websitename. you 'll then get : 
http://yourwebsitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/

Then you can choose for proces explorer -> propertys -> download gcdump. 
The resulting file can be opened in visual studio 2013. You can sort on Size in bytes to try to identify which types are leaking.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for web roles?

Comment: doesn't exist anymore, gcdump won't be supported by vs any longer either

Comment: Hi @albertjan, thanks for the comment. What is the alternative?